# Is the tensor product of UFDs again UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k=\bar{k}$ be an algebraically closed field [Thanks to Mohan for pointing out that this is a necessary assumption in the comments!].

Let $A=k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ and $I=(f_{1},\ldots,f_{r})\subseteq A$ an ideal.
Let $B=k[y_{1},\ldots,y_{m}]$ and $J=(g_{1},\ldots,g_{l})\subseteq B$ an ideal.
Suppose $A/I$ and $B/J$ are unique factorization domains (UFD).
Is the same true for $(A/I)\otimes_{k} (B/J)$?

**Attempt**: thanks to Gauss' lemma we know this to be true when $I=0$ or $J=0$.
So we have an UFD $R:=A\otimes_{k}B$ and two ideals $I\subseteq R$ and $J\subseteq R$ such that both $R/I$ and $R/J$ are UFDs. Moreover, these $2$ ideals come from $A$ and $B$ respectively, so they "do not interact too much with each other". This vague condition, whatever it means, is certainly a necessary condition for the claim to be true, since otherwise we could just intersect a conic in the plane with a line tangent to it to get a counterexample:
$$ R=k[x,y], I=(x), J=(x-y^{2}). $$
But I was not able to make this vague condition precise in algebraic terms, and I am not even sure if I should expect the result to be true or not.

Comment: I didn't mess with elements because I wasn't sure what the irreducibles would be in the tensor product, so I immediately discarded that approach. For example, in the ring $k[x,y]\cong k[x]\otimes_{k}k[y]$, the element $1\otimes y$ is irreducible, but $1$ is not irreducible in $k[x]$. How do you avoid this kind of problem?

**Edit**: this was an answer to a comment suggesting to start from two different factorizations of $a\otimes b$ and deducing the existence of two different factorizations of $a$ or $b$.

Comment: There are field extensions $k\subset K$ such that $K\otimes_k K$ is not a domain, so you have to account for that. If $k$ is algebraically closed, I believe this is true and can be found in Mumford's book (abelian varieties?). The main point is that if $X$ is a projective closure of $\mathrm{Spec}\, A$, then $H^1(X,O_X)=0$.

Comment: Pedro: yeah, apologies about that; I realized that I was spouting nonsense right after I said it, and deleted the comment.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for your example! I have done a word search for "ufd" and for "factorial" in several books by Mumford including the one on abelian varieties and the commutative algebra book by Zariski--Samuel that he references to at some points, but could not find this result. In his Red Book he does talk about factorial varieties for a while, but I didn't find this result. Do you have a better idea of what words to look for? Or perhaps some other reference?

Comment: Mumford deals only with Picard groups, so may be the result is proved only for smooth varieties where Picard and class groups are the same.

Comment: @Mohan I am confused, sorry. What result do you mean? I assumed we were talking about "product of factorial varieties is factorial". But product of smooth varieties is smooth, so probably you have some other result in mind. How does it relate to the question in that case?

Comment: No, Mumford's book proves that if $X, Y$ are smooth projective varieties with $H^1(X,O_X)=0$, then $\mathrm{Pic}(X\times Y)=\mathrm{Pic}\, X\times \mathrm{Pic}\, Y$.

Comment: @Mohan I see, sorry for the confusion. But can you conclude that the class group is trivial from the Picard group being trivial? On a normal scheme the cycle homomorphism is surjective if and only if the scheme is factorial, right? So the class group could be a priori larger than the Picard group. If the class group was trivial, I'd see how to conclude with Proposition II.6.2 in Hartshorne's book. But I am still missing that step. P.S. a precise statement for the result you mention can be found as an exercise in Hartshorne (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/81624/99436)

Comment: For smooth varieties the class group and Picard group are the same. I also suspect that if you are over an algebraically closed field your assertion is indeed true without smoothness. If I come up with an  argument, I will post it.

Comment: @Mohan But this is because smooth varieties are factorial, and that is precisely what we are trying to show. The fact that a normal locally noetherian scheme is factorial if and only if Weil and Cartier divisors are the same has nothing to do with the base field, as far as I know (I am refering to EGAIV, Thm. 21.6.9). So I don't see how to make this work (or why it should work). But thanks for your comments in any case!

Comment: Smooth varieties are only locally factorial. Product of two irreducible varieties may not be irreducible as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Mohan I was using the word factorial in the sense of Mumford's Red Book or Vakil's FOAG (you can see in the reference I gave what I meant by factorial, which is what Grothendieck calls locally factorial). Vakil justifies the choice "factorial" over "locally factorial", warns about this amgiuity and also adds some interesting comments and examples, e.g. 5.4.5 of his FAOG. I didn't forget about your nice example! But I realize now that I didn't edit the question, so I will do it now. Thanks again for your helpful comments!