# Tensor product of UFDs

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We know that the tensor product of polynomial rings over an algebraically closed field is again a polynomial ring, and hence, a UFD. My question is:

> If $R$ and $R'$ are two polynomial rings over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$, and say $I\subset R$ and $J\subset R'$ are two ideals such that $R/I$ and $R'/J$ are UFDs, then is it true that $R/I \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} R'/J$ is a UFD?

Or, at least, is the above statement true when both $I$ and $J$ are principal ideals in their respective polynomial rings over $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: It might happen that $R/I$ or $R/J$ is not even an integral domain.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578801/is-the-tensor-product-of-ufds-again-ufd

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I have seen this, but the discussion seems vague and I don't think it properly answers the question. At least I don't understand, so if you can explain it to me, then that'll be great

Comment: Assume for simplicity that your UFDs are finite type $k$-algebras, with $K$ algebraically closed.  The tensor product $R/I \otimes_k R'/J$ is certainly going to  be Noetherian and normal.  To see normality, recall Serre's condition for normality is that a ring is normal iff it satisfies $R_1$ and $S_2$.  By theorem 1.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210359.pdf, $R_n$ and $S_n$ ascend to the tensor product over a perfect field (which is ok since algebraically closed implies perfect).  Now recall that a Noetherian normal ring is a UFD iff it has trivial Picard group.

Comment: (cont) this doesn't answer your question but it does reduce it the question of when the Picard group of your tensor product will be trivial.  e.g. see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493005/picard-group-of-product-of-spaces.  The answers there show e.g. that if $K(R/I)$ is a purely transcendental extension of $k$ then you have a positive answer to your question.

Comment: @BadamBaplan thanks for your excellent explanation. I was wondering if you can write it in the answer column. Also, I was wondering the result that you mentioned, "a Noetherian normal ring is a UFD iff it has trivial Picard group", isn't the condition on the class group, instead of the Picard group?

Comment: @FreePawn oh geez, yes please replace Picard group by class group in what I said above, it's totally wrong as stated now (e.g. many local normal domains are not UFDs). When writing that I was thinking for some reason that everything was already known to be factorial so the notions would coincide.